# DevExpress.XtraGrid.Menu shows up very slowly (compared to native Winforms menu popup)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

**Update:** I rebooted my machine and it is not as slow as 500 milliseconds, but it still takes about 40 milliseconds just to show the context menu, I compared it against the native Winforms menu (which is faster). Also, I have already verified by setting timestamps that `MyGridMenu.Show` is the bottleneck here, once it is commented out, the whole functions takes nearly no time.

I'm writing a Devexpress xGrid based application, and I need to customize the context menu. I used the following code snippet and the `.Show` function call is really long (500ms). This level of slowness is intolerable for a native application, but I'm really new to C#, Winforms, etc. and I'm out of ideas. Does anyone know what could be the culprit?

```
    private void gridControl1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Detected your mouse up event!");
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.ViewInfo.GridHitInfo hi = view.CalcHitInfo(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            if (!hi.InColumnPanel)
            {
                var MyGridMenu = new ExternalManagerContextualMenuView(view)
                {
                        MyDataStore = this.MyDataStore
                };
                MyGridMenu.Init(hi);
                MyGridMenu.Show(hi.HitPoint);
            }
            var end = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine($"Showing this thing takes {end - start} time");
        }
  }
```

Comment: You'll need to explain what is `ExternalManagerContextualMenuView` and `this.MyDataStore`? I suspect that the slowest part here is custom data binding and not the component itself.

Comment: Not it's not that, I verified that it is the `MyGridMenu.Show()` that's slow by setting timestamps for each line.

Comment: Have you tried to loop through your datasource separately? Otherwise, it doesn't verify anything, before the call to `Show` you only assign a reference to the datasource, the actual data retrieval happens on display. And you still need to explain what is `ExternalManagerContextualMenuView`.

Comment: @defaultlocale `ExternalManagerContextualMenuView` is just a subclass of `DataGridMenuView`, the data source contain 10 simple objects, (which I reduced from original 1000 and didn't notice any improvement).

Answer (score 0):

GridView provides the [PopupMenuShowing](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.PopupMenuShowing.event) event that allows you to add your custom menu items. In this case, you will not need to handle the MouseUp event.

As for the latency issue, it is likely that it is caused by the following code:

```
    var MyGridMenu = new ExternalManagerContextualMenuView(view)
{
        MyDataStore = this.MyDataStore
};
MyGridMenu.Init(hi);
MyGridMenu.Show(hi.HitPoint);
```

You can measure how much time these lines take by using Stopwatch.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
//your code
sw.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```